# Minimal installation details

Tags: ubuntu-minimal

Ubuntu 18.04 brings a new feature "minimal installation". I could not find any official documentation about which packages are not installing when we checked "minimal installation".

Can you please provide a source/doc for package list?

Comment: As you’ve never accepted an answer before: if an answer answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the number at the left of it to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!

Answer (score 11):

```
# This is a list of packages to be removed when the 'minimal' option is
# selected during installation.

# Note that the format is NOT the same as the usual seed format. This file is
# not processed by germinate - it is simply downloaded during image builds.

# Desktop apps
thunderbird
transmission-gtk
gnome-todo
baobab
rhythmbox
cheese
vino
shotwell
totem
usb-creator-gtk
deja-dup
gnome-calendar
remmina
simple-scan

# Desktop experience
thunderbird-gnome-support

# Games
aisleriot
gnome-mahjongg
gnome-mines
gnome-sudoku
branding-ubuntu

# Libreoffice
libreoffice-style-breeze
libreoffice-gnome
libreoffice-writer
libreoffice-calc
libreoffice-impress
libreoffice-math
libreoffice-ogltrans
libreoffice-pdfimport

# Others
example-content
ubuntu-web-launchers

# Langpacks (keeping libreoffice and thunderbird installed otherwise)
libreoffice-l10n-en-gb
libreoffice-l10n-es
libreoffice-l10n-zh-cn
libreoffice-l10n-zh-tw
libreoffice-l10n-pt
libreoffice-l10n-pt-br
libreoffice-l10n-de
libreoffice-l10n-fr
libreoffice-l10n-it
libreoffice-l10n-ru
libreoffice-l10n-en-za
libreoffice-help-en-gb
libreoffice-help-es
libreoffice-help-zh-cn
libreoffice-help-zh-tw
libreoffice-help-pt
libreoffice-help-pt-br
libreoffice-help-de
libreoffice-help-fr
libreoffice-help-it
libreoffice-help-ru
libreoffice-help-en-us
thunderbird-locale-en
thunderbird-locale-en-gb
thunderbird-locale-en-us
thunderbird-locale-es
thunderbird-locale-es-ar
thunderbird-locale-es-es
thunderbird-locale-zh-cn
thunderbird-locale-zh-hans
thunderbird-locale-zh-hant
thunderbird-locale-zh-tw
thunderbird-locale-pt
thunderbird-locale-pt-br
thunderbird-locale-pt-pt
thunderbird-locale-de
thunderbird-locale-fr
thunderbird-locale-it
thunderbird-locale-ru

# Unused rdepends
gir1.2-rb-3.0
gir1.2-totem-1.0
gir1.2-totemplparser-1.0
guile-2.0-libs
libabw-0.1-1
libavahi-ui-gtk3-0
libdmapsharing-3.0-2
libexttextcat-2.0-0
libexttextcat-data
libfreehand-0.1-1
libgnome-games-support-1-3
libgnome-games-support-common
libgom-1.0-0
libgrilo-0.3-0
liblangtag-common
liblangtag1
libmessaging-menu0
libmhash2
libminiupnpc10
libmwaw-0.3-3
libmythes-1.2-0
libnatpmp1
libneon27-gnutls
liborcus-0.13-0
libpagemaker-0.0-0
librdf0
libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer
libreoffice-base-core
libreoffice-common
libreoffice-core
libreoffice-draw
libreoffice-gtk3
libreoffice-style-elementary
libreoffice-style-galaxy
libreoffice-style-tango
libraptor2-0
librasqal3
librevenge-0.0-0
librhythmbox-core10
libtotem0
libvisio-0.1-1
libwpd-0.10-10
libwpg-0.3-3
libwps-0.4-4
libyajl2
python3-uno
rhythmbox-data
rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar
rhythmbox-plugins
remmina-common
remmina-plugin-rdp
remmina-plugin-secret
remmina-plugin-vnc
duplicity
seahorse-daemon
shotwell-common
totem-common
totem-plugins
transmission-common
cheese-common
gnome-todo-common
libgnome-todo
gnome-video-effects
libcheese-gtk25
libcheese8
uno-libs3
ure
zeitgeist-core
hunspell-de-at-frami
hunspell-de-ch-frami
hunspell-de-de-frami
hunspell-en-au
hunspell-en-ca
hunspell-en-gb
hunspell-en-za
hunspell-es
hunspell-fr
hunspell-fr-classical
hunspell-it
hunspell-pt-br
hunspell-pt-pt
hunspell-ru
hyphen-de
hyphen-en-ca
hyphen-en-gb
hyphen-en-us
hyphen-fr
hyphen-hr
hyphen-it
hyphen-pl
hyphen-pt-br
hyphen-pt-pt
hyphen-ru
mythes-de
mythes-de-ch
mythes-en-au
mythes-en-us
mythes-fr
mythes-it
mythes-pt-pt
mythes-ru
```

Source: [Currently a dead link](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-core-dev/ubuntu-seeds/ubuntu.bionic/view/head:/desktop.minimal-remove)

Comment: tnx for the effort. @arochester

Answer (score 6):

A list of packages removed as part of the minimal install was available at what is currently a [dead link](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-core-dev/ubuntu-seeds/ubuntu.bionic/view/head:/desktop.minimal-remove).

This same dead link is included in this post: [Breeze through Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS Bionic Beaver](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2018/04/27/breeze-through-ubuntu-desktop-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver).

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I found [this post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/9f8o0d/minimal_vs_normal_installation/e5vffbd/) while looking for an answer to this as well. It has current links for all the Ubuntu variants that support it (which are listed below for reference, too).

- [Ubuntu Minimal](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/seeds/ubuntu.bionic/desktop.minimal-remove)
- [Kubuntu Minimal](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/seeds/kubuntu.bionic/desktop.minimal-remove)
- [Ubuntu Mate Minimal (dev)](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mate-dev/ubuntu-seeds/ubuntu-mate.bionic/view/head:/desktop.minimal-remove)
- [Ubuntu Mate Minimal](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/seeds/ubuntu-mate.bionic/desktop.minimal-remove)
- [Lubuntu Minimal (QT)](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/seeds/lubuntu.bionic/desktop-qt.minimal-remove)
- [Lubuntu Minimal (GTK)](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/seeds/lubuntu.bionic/desktop-gtk.minimal-remove)
- [Ubuntu Budgie](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/seeds/ubuntu-budgie.bionic/desktop.minimal-remove)