# Remove braille and assistive technology packages

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.04, uninstall, cleanup

I don't need braille packages on my system. So I did:

`sudo apt purge brltty brltty-x11 libbrlapi0.6 python3-brlapi xbrlapi`

However I just discovered there is also `liblouis-data`. There are probably more packages that I don't know about.

How do I remove everything related to braille, without messing up my system?

(If there are other assistive technologies installed by default, I'd like to remove those too.)

Comment: Posting as a comment because this doesn't directly answer your question (and is partly outdated) but you should look at the community maintained [Diet Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Diet%20Ubuntu) page for packages which are safe to remove. This includes accessibility, dial-up, bluetooth, and other utilities beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: @TomBrossman That's really helpful, thanks a lot - though it's really out of date. I wish there were something similar for a more recent ubuntu version.

Comment: I still use that page to refer to for new installs, as recently as 18.04, but do watch carefully for what is being uninstalled and dependencies that will also be removed, so you don't have any nasty surprises.

Comment: @TomBrossman At least for Bionic, wouldn't a comparison of what's installed by choosing the minimal install option versus the full install option provide an updated "Diet Ubuntu"?

Comment: Finding that comparison list was surprisingly difficult but I don't [see any accessibility packages on it](https://askubuntu.com/a/1036557/12864). Not a bad idea for an updated "Diet" list though, but it doesn't help with OP's question.